# await fetch does not seem to wait

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch-api

I have some code calling to load the same template really fast. I've tried to implement a simple caching system to only fetch when the template wasn't previously loaded, but I can't seem to get the await to truly wait until the function is completed.

The code for the template loading system:

```
    var arrContent = []; //array of objects: {"url":"http://...", "content": "<div>..."}
    var content = null;
    this.loadFile = async function(url){
        
        //Check if the content was already loaded
        let i = findContentIndex(url);
        if(i != null){ // The template already exist, simply load it from memory
            console.log("Cached!");
            content = arrContent[i].content;
        }else{
            //Content is not already in cache, load it from the url
            console.log("Fetching...");
            await fetch(url)
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    content = response;
                    arrContent.push({"url": url, "content": content});
                })
                .catch( 
                    function() {
                        error =>  console.log(error);
                    }
                );
            console.log("content");
        }
}

function findContentIndex(url){
    for(let i=0; i<arrContent.length; i++)
        if(arrContent[i].url != undefined && arrContent[i].url == url)
            return i;
    return null;
}

this.render = function(){
    //...
}
```

What I end up is with an array containing many duplicate of the same template URL, where as the code should prevent duplicate from happening.

For context, the calls are made this way. Multiple calls within a few ms of each others:

```
await Tpl.loadFile(chrome.runtime.getURL("view/widget.html"));
let content = Tpl.render();
```

The output will look something like:

```
Fetching...
Fetching...
Fetching...
Fetching...
Fetching...
content
content
content
content
content
```

Instead of:

```
Fetching...
content
Cached!
Cached!
Cached!
Cached!
```

If I could have the entire LoadFile function executed just once at the time it would solve my problem.

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Just return from the promise. Don’t mix then/catch with await. Think procedurally

Comment: Cache the promise itself (immediately), not the result (after receiving it)

Comment: The code seems to be modifying a variable inside an async function, but expecting it to be modified synchronously

Comment: If you call the function really fast then the first Promise won't have resolved and cached yet. So seeing it fetching multiple times is expected. You should have 1 Promise which all the calls wait on instead of creating new ones each time. You should also show the code which calls `Tpl.loadFile` as the problem is there.

Comment: Not many good reasons to use `var` any more.

Comment: @evolutionxbox correct, that's what I'm doing wrong I think.

Comment: @Bergi when I tried to do that, the render method received null content. I'm really at loss for words...

Comment: @DanielA.White How may I do that?

Comment: Try to implement a simple locking mechanism.

Comment: @DaviAmaral that’s a bad idea

Comment: @DanielA.White I disagree

Comment: @Dominic For all intent and purpose, you can assume the calls are in a for loop. In reality it's a few method deeper from a loop over DOM objects but we can simplify this as being a simple for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your caching system only works after the result has been received, but not while it still is loading. To fix this, store the promise itself in the cache, and store it immediately when starting the request.

```
/** array of objects: {"url":"http://...", "promise": Promise<"<div>...">} */
const cache  = [];
this.loadFile = function(url){
    // Check if the content was already loading
    let entry = cache.find(e => e.url === url);
    if (entry != null) {
        // The template already started loading, simply return the same promise again
        console.log("Cached!");
    } else {
        // Content is not already in cache, load it from the url
        console.log("Fetching...");
        const promise = fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
                return response.text();
            });
        entry = { url, promise };
        cache.push(entry);
    }
    return entry.promise;
}
```

Notice I also changed the function to **return** the (promise for the) content, not store it in some shared variable (which is highly perilous when `loadFile` and `render` are called multiple times from async code). Then call the function as follows:

```
try {
    const template = await Tpl.loadFile(chrome.runtime.getURL("view/widget.html"));
    const content = Tpl.render(template);
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Btw I'd also recommend to use a `Map` for the `cache` instead of an array of objects.

Comment: Using a Map object for caching instead of an array is a great recommendation. Maps provide better performance for dynamic sets of keys and are more suited for key-value associations like cache entries.

Comment: Wow, this work so well. I won't pretend to have a firm grasp on how you implemented the promise portion, but now that I have a base to work with, I can study it. Thank you so much, and BTW, you are welcome to improve the code with Map for the cache, this is not a case of "it had to be an array because reasons".